# What is this product equal to?

Tags: prime-numbers, products

I recently came across the following product over prime numbers, but lost the source of the formula. Can someone enlighten me? The product, taken over all primes $p$, is:

$$
\prod _{p}^{\infty} \frac{p^2 \left(1-p+p^2\right)}{1-p+p^2-p^3+p^4}.
$$

Incidentally, Mathematica tells me that it is approximately equal to:

$$
\frac{1}{34} \sqrt{\frac{1}{6} \left(19 \sqrt{237673}-239\right)}.
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$ \frac{p^2(1-p+p^2)}{1-p+p^2-p^3+p^4} = \frac{1+1/p^3}{1+1/p^5}$$
Now use the [Euler products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product)
$$ \prod_p (1 + 1/p^s) = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$$
so your infinite product is $$ \frac{\zeta(3) \zeta(10)}{\zeta(6) \zeta(5)}$$

Comment: It would be truly amazing if this ratio of zetas were exactly equal to $$\frac{1}{34} \sqrt{\frac{1}{6} \left(19 \sqrt{237673}-239\right)}.$$

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  The difference between them is about $4.3 \times 10^{-12}$.  
Note that $\zeta(10)/\zeta(6) = \pi^4/99$.  It is conjectured that $\pi$ and the odd zetas are algebraically independent.  If so, $\zeta(3) \zeta(10)/(\zeta(6)\zeta(5))$ must be transcendental.